# User Management, application access control, logging etc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, sharepoint-2010

We have many custom asp.net applications which need user management (login, authentication, lost password, add or delete users, update profile etc.), logging (actions, search logs, connection problems etc.), content approval and content upload.

Each application is duplicating the above functionality and I would like to centralize it.

My question is:

Can I create 1 custom asp.net application which will use the WSS at the back end to handle most of the above? So basically I will create a web user interface and use the sharepoint sdk and database to do the aforementioned.

Or do you have some other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this 
http://sharepoint2010fba.codeplex.com/